# Using the 'new' modifier with interfaces at a given index like 'var b = new ISomeInterface[0];', what does it mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax, interface, modifiers

I've come across the following C# syntax for the first time, I would have discarded it as a syntax error except that VS is absolutely happy with it and compiles.

```
var a = new ISomeInterface[0];
```

The interface is declared as

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
}
```

Links to further reading are also highly appreciated.

Comment: Move your mouse over the `var` keyword: it'll show you the actual type (i.e. an array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created an array of `ISomeInterface`.

This is the same as declaring any other array, such as:

```
string[] a = new string[0];
```

I kinda did a double-take on that at first too, because at first glance it appeared the code was instantiating an interface, something you can't normally do.

Answer (score 2):

It is creating a **new array** (zero-length), not a new instance of the interface. Incidentally, you can actually `new` an interface... under the right conditions ;p (COM attributes)

Comment: I don't know if I'm more honored to have my question answered by Marc Gravell himself or more ashamed in realising I have asked such a silly question! Anyway thanks! =)